# How to select records in mysql based from array of category id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where the table has a category field is array value
LIKE :

```
|-----------------------------------|
|post_id  |   name   |  category_id |
-------------------------------------
|1        |  test1   |  1,2,45      |
|2        |  test2   |  2,7         |
|3        |  test3   |  7,13,56     |
|-----------------------------------|
```

From drop down select box if i select CATEGORY ID 2. i should get the result of TWO ROWS. because post_id 1 and 2 have 2 in category_id. i don't know how to do query for it. i struggled a lot. please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that is your database design you should change the design. Having category_id as a comma separated string is not a good idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If posts can be in multiple categories, then you should reconsider the use of arrays in the category_id field, and instead use a post/category reference table, with a structure such as:

```
id  postId  catId
```

This way, you can get all posts in category 2 by (lets call this reference table 'PostCats'):

```
SELECT postId FROM PostCats WHERE catId=2
```

Comment: if category_id has single value, i can go for 'category_id = 2'. but category_id like (4,5,1,2) the field is in array value. how can i do for this ? thanks

Comment: And thats a very nice solution. To the OP never never store data with comma separation string, normalize the table as @flauntster has described.

Comment: thanks for opinion for normalize the table. sure i planned to do your way. thank you so much..

Comment: @muralidego, if the post is in multiple categories, then it has multiple rows in the post/cat reference table, with each row reflecting each category it is in :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to sort this out.
You can change the datatype of `category_id` to `SET` and using something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', category_id);`

*Read more:* [**FIND_IN_SET**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Also look at [**flauntster' answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23649257/2518525) for the most appropriate way to do it.

Comment: I think it actually works on varchars too - not that I would ever recommend it. :)

Comment: @JoelHinz Agree with you 100%. Would not do it this way at all! :P

Comment: @muralidego It's a pleasure.